# Delay computations in shiny with handsontable

Tags: r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

In the MRE below, the user is asked to filled in a table from which a curved is plotted. To mimic some computation, occurring on the table before producing graphical output, I added a `Sys.sleep()`. You will see that if the table is filled sufficiently fast, i.e. faster than the `Sys.sleep()`, the application become unusable and have to be killed.

I believe this is because table rendering is occurring after computation/sleep and plot rendering. How should I address this issue to make the app react in real time and still be usable ?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(x=integer(0), y=integer(0))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  mainPanel( 
    rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
      DF <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    } else {
      if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
        DF <- DF
      else
        DF <- values[["DF"]]
    }
    values[["DF"]] <- DF
  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values[["DF"]], stretchH = "all", minRows=5)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

      table <- {
        Sys.sleep(.4)
        values[["DF"]]
        }

      ggplot(data=table) + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y))

  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to add an `actionButton()` labeled "Update graph"? You could then wrap any computation in an `observeEvent()` . This way your users won't see any graph render for half completed entries.

Comment: That would be one solution, yes. But I really enjoy to see the plot updates in real-time, it really makes my app beautiful and was working fine until recently. It only became uncomfortable after recent change in computations, making them slightly more demanding, and especially after uploading the app on `shinyapps.io` where it is completely unusable because of reduced computing power.

Comment: A possible solution (that I have not tried) is to make use of the [promise package](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/) for async capabilities. I don't know if shinyapps.io supports this though.

Comment: I'm reading it but it is complicated... I have an idea that I dont now how to implement. Would you now how to implement a timer that would condition the execution of the `renderPlot` (including computation and plot rendering) on the fact that the table has not been incremented for 1second for example ?

Comment: A messy and hacky way to do this would be to create a reactive variable that stored sys.time() whenever a variable is changed (put `input` inside a `reactiveValue()` ) and put all computation inside an `if` statement that checks that reactive value against sys.time() for a set interval.